# How to construct a Dataflow collection from Avro files with different schemas?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

How can you construct a PCollection from Avro files when the schema for each file could be one of N different schemas?

We'd like to just specify a glob path matching all the avro files and we'd like to use a single Avro source rather than constructing a new Avro source for each file?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is using an Avro source and specifying a schema which is the union of all such files. This will yield a PCollection where the records are GenericReccords whose schema is the union of all the different schemas. You can then apply a ParDo operation in order to convert them to whatever representation you desire.

Here's a [complete example](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/a6f3f3e737906c165a26af4dd3706e4de7b0545c/dataflow/src/main/java/dataflow/UnionExample.java?at=master)